# How to create a function that multiples every elements in a list by any number when the function is called

Tags: python-3.x

For example: (fill in the blank in the for loop)

```py
my_list = [1,3,5,7,9]

def multiply_list_by(alist, multiplier):
    """
    Returns a new list that multiplies each element of alist
    by the multiplier, so that the new list is the same length
    as alist, and the n'th element of new_list is equal to
    multiplier times the n'th element of alist
    """
    new_list = []
    
    for elem in my_list():
        new_list.append(___)
    return new_list
```

Expected output

```py
multiply_list_by(my_list, 10)
# the result should be [10, 30, 50, 70, 90]
```

Comment: `my_list` isn't a function, but you're calling it like it is one. To iterate over an iterable, you just need `for item in iterable`. The parentheses are for calling functions. Also, do you understand what that `for` loop is doing? Do you know what `elem` is on each iteration? This is a very straightforward problem and if you can't figure it out you need to go back and get a refresher on the basics of the Python language.

Comment: Yes this is a very basic question and it's from a beginner python course, I am a python beginner

Comment: All you need to do is multiply `elem` by `multiplier`...

Comment: Do you understand what's happening in the `for` loop? Do you know what `new_list.append()` does?

Comment: I know the new_list.append is to append the new item after the multiplying to the new_list

Comment: So what function should I call? for elem in ___():

Comment: You don't need to call any function. You need to iterate over the elements of `alist`, the parameter for your function which will be a list of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by list comprehension, but if you want to use loop, then use for loop. Using for loop, you can iterate the list, multiply each element with the multiplier and add it to another empty list say y, finally display y. Your code:

```
my_list=[1,3,5,7,9]
def multiply_list_by(my_list,multiplier):
    y=[]
    for i in my_list:
        y.append(i*multiplier)
    return y

print(multiply_list_by(my_list,10))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply multiply `multiplier` by your element called `elem`:

```
my_list = [1,3,5,7,9]

def multiply_list_by(alist, multiplier):
    """
    Returns a new list that multiplies each element of alist
    by the multiplier, so that the new list is the same length
    as alist, and the n'th element of new_list is equal to
    multiplier times the n'th element of alist
    """
    new_list = []
    
    for elem in alist:
        new_list.append(elem * multiplier)
    return new_list
print(multiply_list_by([1,3,5,7,9], 10))
```

Comment: @nomoresky You also had `my_list()` inside your function instead of `alist` which was causing a compiler error

Answer (score -1):

The answer can be:

`def multiply_list_by(alist, multiplier): return [a*multiplier for a in alist]`

Answer (score -1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```py
def f(l,m):
 return [x*m for x in l]

print(f([1,3,5,7,9],10))
```